# Flutter firebase_performance package : Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-performance

I have added firebase_performance package in my flutter project. But when running the project, it exists after build showing the error **Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process**. But i have already added the code `Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,);` in main.dart file.

```
Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk...                 5.8s
E/AndroidRuntime(23097): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(23097): Process: com.example.demo_app, PID: 23097
E/AndroidRuntime(23097): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.demo_app/com.example.demo_app.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.demo_app. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
E/AndroidRuntime(23097):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4884)
E/AndroidRuntime(23097):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4922)
E/AndroidRuntime(23097):        at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:52)
E/AndroidRuntime(23097):        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
E/AndroidRuntime(23097):        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
E/AndroidRuntime(23097):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2414)
E/AndroidRuntime(23097):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(23097):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:265)
E/AndroidRuntime(23097):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8360)
E/AndroidRuntime(23097):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(23097):        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:632)
E/AndroidRuntime(23097):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1049)
E/AndroidRuntime(23097): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.demo_app. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
E/AndroidRuntime(23097):        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(FirebaseApp.java:186)
E/AndroidRuntime(23097):        at com.google.firebase.perf.FirebasePerformance.getInstance(FirebasePerformance.java:132)
E/AndroidRuntime(23097):        at com.google.firebase.perf.FirebasePerformanceInitializer.onAppColdStart(FirebasePerformanceInitializer.java:29)
E/AndroidRuntime(23097):        at com.google.firebase.perf.application.AppStateMonitor.sendAppColdStartUpdate(AppStateMonitor.java:322)
E/AndroidRuntime(23097):        at com.google.firebase.perf.application.AppStateMonitor.onActivityResumed(AppStateMonitor.java:240)
E/AndroidRuntime(23097):        at android.app.Application.dispatchActivityResumed(Application.java:451)
E/AndroidRuntime(23097):        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResumed(Activity.java:1437)
E/AndroidRuntime(23097):        at android.app.Activity.onResume(Activity.java:1967)
E/AndroidRuntime(23097):        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onResume(FragmentActivity.java:310)
E/AndroidRuntime(23097):        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1463)
E/AndroidRuntime(23097):        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:8294)
E/AndroidRuntime(23097):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4874)
E/AndroidRuntime(23097):        ... 11 more
```

Comment: Do you have google-services.json in the project?

Comment: @activout.se i have already added that. I also updated it now and the issue still exists

Answer (score 0):

What does your main.dart file look like? When I first started working with FireBase I often forgot to make the main function asychronous. Assuming you've configured everything the FireBase, your main should look something like this:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Let me know if you 've already done that.

Comment: I have already added this code, but not working

Comment: Also the issue is only with `firebase_performance`. Other packages such as `firebase_dynamic_links` and `firebase_messaging` are working fine.

Comment: Re-running the commands `dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli` and `flutterfire configure` solved the issue